# Beginner, Error in python regarding site-packages/celltool/numerics/fitpack/_fitpack.so

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing some image analysis for my research, and it involves using CellTool (http://pantheon.yale.edu/~zp2/Celltool/), Python, and numpy. I'm on a OS X 10.8.3. On my old laptop that crashed, I was able to run my commands fine, but I got a new one and things are not going as smoothly!

I *believe* I have CellTool and numpy installed correctly, and I'm just using Python 2.7.2 that's standard on Mac. But when I try to run this python script "calculate_distances.py" command, I get this error:

```
Yuxins-MacBook-Pro:Modified_Contours yuxinsun$ python calculate_distances.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calculate_distances.py", line 24, in <module>
    normals = contours[n-1].inward_normals()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celltool/contour/contour_class.py", line 384, in inward_normals
    import celltool.numerics.fitpack as fitpack
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celltool/numerics/fitpack/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fitpack import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celltool/numerics/fitpack/fitpack.py", line 34, in <module>
    import _fitpack
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celltool/numerics/fitpack/_fitpack.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celltool/numerics/fitpack/_fitpack.so
  Reason: image not found
```

And I have no idea what any of it means...I only need to run this python script and get the file that it spits out.

Am I just missing the "fitpack" whatever that is? If so, how do I install it? Or what can I do to fix this problem.

Comment: Looks like something is up with your fitpack installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you have those installed per installation requirements:

```
If one of the above binary installers did not suit your needs, 
please install Celltool from the source code. 
This depends on only three things:

1.Python (version 2.3 or later).
2. NumPy 1.0.4 or later.
3. Working C/C++ and Fortran compilers.
```

and it looks like your Fortran compiler libs are not installed.

This might be helpful: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/how-should-i-install-a-fortran-compiler-on-a-mac-os-x-10-x-x-4

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have xcode installed, but I'm not sure what to do with it or if it's sufficient?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out! I installed gfortran. Thanks!